# Flash and .dll to only one file

Tags: flash, dll

I want to make my application as one file. But I have a problem with packing DLL and other files. Does anyone have a ideas on this? I need only one file! I heard that something similar can be done with utilities...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hmmmm...
I would use flajector or f-in-box, in your case. There are also many other features that enhance the capabilities of Flash Player.
The second has many features, including it can collect all files into one file exe (there may even include flash player). You will hardly find other ways.

Answer (score 2):

I use the f-in-box a long time - cool library!